# Jmeter- I have scenario where Users login once and does various transactions multiple times in a thread

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Jmeter -->I need to do load test a scenario with 10 different users should login **only once** and other transactions should be done for multiple times ( might be using Thread) . And the 10 Authorization  of all users should be used in other transactions.

I tried "IF controller" with code "${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0 &&  vars.getIteration() == 1,)}" but authorization is used only once in other transactions

Once only controller also used -- Not working .. I think i am missing some logic here.

[JmeterScreenshot_Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suApx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Given your current implementation only 1st user will be logged in, others will skip the `login` request
2. Given you have 200 threads (virtual users) **each of them** needs to be logged in, authentication context is [local to the thread](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/threadlocal.html) (virtual user)

So if you plan to authenticate only 10 users, remaining 190 will not be authenticated hence all Transaction Controller children will be failing.

A good solution would be requesting more credentials so each of 200 users could have it's own username/password combination.

If a single user can be logged in only once and it's not possible to have more credentials, as a workaround you can authenticate 10 users somewhere in the [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) and then pass the authentication context ([cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), [tokens](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/Europe/events/foaf-galway/papers/fp/token_based_authentication/), whatever) to the main Thread Group via [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)